# Java color changing Graphics with Timer

Tags: java, swing, graphics, timer

I want to draw a disc that changes colors twice a second. The disk is drawn on a DrawPanel which extends a JPanel and in the main method the DrawPanel is added to a frame. 
For the colorchanging I use a timer which works when I'm trying to change the background of the DrawPanel in the main method (what i commented out).

Can someone tell me why it doesn't work for the Graphics g object or any other suggestions?

I just copied the code from the main method and added it into the paintComponent() method, but here it doesn't work.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel{

    public GridBagLayout gbl;

    //position and dimension
    int x = 0, y = 0, width = 200, height = 200;

    public DrawPanel(){
        repaint();
    }

    public DrawPanel(GridBagLayout gridBagLayout) {
        this.gbl = gridBagLayout;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        //Overwriting of old picture
        super.paintComponent(g);

        ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Random gen = new Random();

                Color color = new Color(gen.nextInt(256), gen.nextInt(256), gen.nextInt(256));

                //Draw color disk
                g.setColor(color);
                g.fillArc(x, y, width, height, 0, 360);
            }
        };

        Timer t = new Timer(500, action);
        t.setRepeats(true);
        t.setInitialDelay(0);
        t.start();



        //Draw boundary of circle
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawArc(x, y, width, height, 0, 360);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        final DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
            panel.setOpaque(true);
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

//      ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {
//          @Override
//          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//              Random gen = new Random();
//                  Color color = new Color(gen.nextInt(256), gen.nextInt(256), gen.nextInt(256));
//                  panel.setBackground(color);         
//          }
//      };
//
//      Timer t = new Timer(500, action);
//      t.setRepeats(true);
//      t.setInitialDelay(0);
//      t.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: The paint methods are not in our direct control and might be called whenever the JVM feels the UI needs to be repainted, and that might happen due to many different conditions.  That is **not** the time to be establishing new timers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Graphics` object is transient, so you should not cache it even if the compiler allows that.  Instead establish the timer in the constructor of the class, set the BG of the panel, then call for a repaint.  E.G.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

    Random gen = new Random();
    //position and dimension
    int x = 0, y = 0, width = 200, height = 200;
    Color drawColor = Color.BLACK;

    public DrawPanel() {
        repaint();
        ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Color color = new Color(gen.nextInt(256), gen.nextInt(256), gen.nextInt(256));

                //Draw color disk
                drawColor = color;
                DrawPanel.this.repaint();
            }
        };

        Timer t = new Timer(500, action);
        t.setRepeats(true);
        t.setInitialDelay(0);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //Overwriting of old picture
        super.paintComponent(g);

        //Draw boundary of circle
        g.setColor(drawColor);
        g.drawArc(x, y, width, height, 0, 360);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        final DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting part of it, the background isn't changing, the disc color is.  Also, I think `setBackground` might automatically repaint the panel to update it, I'll have to check once I'm at a computer

Comment: Well just to make things clear, I only want to change the color of the disc and not of the background. The color of the background is supposed to keep its default color. I just tried it with the background to see if i use the timer is used correctly.

Comment: @mabu, you should create a property of your class like `setDiscColor(...)`. Then when the Timer fires you invoke this method to set the property to your random color. Then the setDiscColor(...) method will invoke repaint(). Then in the painting method you use the disc color property to paint your disc. A painting method should not randomly set Colors because you can't control when the painting method is invoked.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, thanks, changing  g.drawArc(x, y, width, height, 0, 360) to g.fillArc(..) runs it as i wanted it to be, at least with the given frame of the main method. Using this drawPanel in a GUI unfortunately only works halfway using GridbagLayout. By halfway i mean that only a part of the disc changes color and but two "corners" don't. Resizing the window changes the color of the whole circle but when the next colorchange happens i have the same problem.Any suggestions why these two things don't accord?

Comment: *"Any suggestions.."* I suggest you ask a new question (on a new message thread).

Answer (score 2):

Graphics objects are only valid for that one draw

It would be better to instead to tell the JPanel to change it's current color (with a variable) and then tell it to repaint

1. Add variable `discColor` to your JPanel
2. Change your drawing code to not use timers and instead make it simple, just draw the disc based off of `discColor`
3. With a timer, update the `discColor` variable and then call the panel's `repaint()` method