# drawingPanel color change with displacement

Tags: java, swing, colors, jgrasp, custom-painting

I'm using JGrasp, and in `drawingPanel`, I'm trying to create a ball that changes colors as it moves across the screen. Right now, I've got:

```
for (int i = 10; i<=i; i++) {
    Color c = new Color(i*i, 0, 0);
    pen.setColor(c);
```

My full simplified code is:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Color;

public class BallSample {
   public static final int SIZE = 30;
   public static final int HALF = SIZE / 2;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

      DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(1000, 1000);
      panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
      Graphics pen = panel.getGraphics();

      for (int i = 10; i<=i; i++) {
         Color c = new Color(i*i, 0, 0);
         pen.setColor(c);
         pen.fillOval(500 - HALF, 500 - HALF, SIZE, SIZE);

         double xDisplacement = 30 * Math.cos(30);
         double yDisplacement = 30 * Math.sin(30) * -1;
         double x = 500.0;
         double y = 500.0;

         for (int j = 1; j <= 100; j++) {
            x = x + xDisplacement;
            y = y + yDisplacement;
         if (x <= 0 || x >= 1000) {
            xDisplacement = xDisplacement * -1;
         }
         if (y <= 0 || y >= 1000) {
            yDisplacement = yDisplacement * -1;
         }
            pen.fillOval((int) x - HALF, (int) y - HALF, SIZE, SIZE);

            panel.sleep(50);
         }      
      }
   }
}
```

I hope that's simplified enough.

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mcve] that shows your issue. Not a code snippet nor your whole code, but rather a new simple program showing a ball that moves from left to right for example and you try to change its color while doing so. By the way, is this Swing? JavaFX? Where are you executing the loop you showed?

Comment: Where is `DrawingPanel`? We don't have that class. You don't need the `Scanner` class in this case either... `panel.sleep(50);` that seems so wrong...

Comment: That's true, I don't need scanner or panel.sleep in the simplified version. Also, I thought that drawingPanel was an actual class, but it turns out that my professors created it: http://www.buildingjavaprograms.com/drawingpanel/DrawingPanel.java

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me even though I keep screwing up...

Comment: It looks like my professors made it in conjunction with their textbook: https://www.amazon.com/Building-Java-Programs-Basics-Approach/dp/0134322762/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_0?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=F4FM2THQ323RSQPFP3BP

Answer (score 0):

After having [some issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779919/swing-custom-painting-animation-stops-after-reaching-half-width-of-frame) in the following code, I was able to create a color-changing ball example.

First of all, having `panel.sleep(50);` makes me think (and I confirm with the [DrawingPanel](http://www.buildingjavaprograms.com/drawingpanel/DrawingPanel.java) class link you posted in the comments) could become dangerous, it would be better to use a [`Swing Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead, however I don't pretend on using or read all the class as it's too long, so in the example I post here I'll be using the Swing `Timer` approach.

Also, I'm not sure why calling [`new Color(int rgb)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int)) constructor with a random `int` (between 0 and 255) doesn't update or create a new `Color` with those settings, then after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33393310/2180785) and another one (I lost its link, sorry), you can use [`new Color(float r, float g, float b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(float,%20float,%20float)), so you may use it with a random number up to `256`.

You can also base your approach to a MVC pattern, having a Model `Ball` class which contains the coords and the `Color` it will have, a View `JPanel` that will draw the ball over time and a Controller that will change the ball's coords and color overtime as well.

**Disclaimer:** This example just moves the ball horizontally and doesn't validate whether it's on the screen or not, you need to adapt this example to your own needs.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ChangingColorBall {
    private JFrame frame;
    private Timer timer;
    private BallPane ballPane;
    private Ball ball;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ChangingColorBall()::createAndShowGui); //We place our program on the EDT
    }
    
    private void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());
        ball = new Ball();
        ballPane = new BallPane(ball);
        
        timer = new Timer(100, e -> { //This Timer will execute every 100ms and will increase ball's X coord and paint it again.
            ball.increaseX(); //This method increases X coord and changes ball's color on the model
            ballPane.revalidate();
            ballPane.repaint();
        });
        
        frame.add(ballPane);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        timer.start(); //We start the timer
    }
    
    class Ball {
        private int xCoord;
        private static final int Y = 50;
        private static final int SIZE = 20;
        private Color color;
        private Random r;
        
        public void increaseX() {
            xCoord += 10; //Increases X coord
            r = new Random();
            color = new Color(r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256)); //Generates a new random color
        }
        
        public int getXCoord() {
            return xCoord;
        }

        public void setXCoord(int xCoord) {
            this.xCoord = xCoord;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class BallPane extends JPanel {
        private Ball ball;
        
        public BallPane(Ball ball) {
            this.ball = ball;
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { //This method paints the ball according to the color it has and the actual coords it has
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            
            g2d.setColor(ball.getColor());
            g2d.fillOval(ball.getXCoord(), Ball.Y, Ball.SIZE, Ball.SIZE);
        }
        
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() { //We should not call `.setSize(...)` method, so we override this one and call `.pack();` 
            return new Dimension(200, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Note

Be aware to not call your coords as `x` or `y` or at least don't call their getters and setters as `getX()` or `getY()` or you could run into the issue I linked at the beginning of this answer.

Here's an example of how the GUI looks like, I can't do GIFs in my computer but it's better if you copy-paste the code and see how it works.

[image]

For a deeper understanding on how custom painting works in Swing, check Oracle's [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) tutorials.