# (multiple image ) animation Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have got a set of nodes in my program, each have a specific x,y location. 
and each have a set of image icons.

I want to draw image animation for each nodes at its specific location.

Here is my code: (this only shows the last image which i know why!.)

```
public void showPicture()  {
        //nodes : 
        for(int i=0;i<thisGraph.getNode().size();i++){
            if(thisGraph.getNode().get(i).getImageIcon()!=(null)){
                for(int j=0;j<thisGraph.getNode().get(i).getImageIcon().size();j++){
                    if(j>0)
                       lables.get(lables.size()-1).setVisible(false);
                    JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();
                    lables.add(jLabel1);
                    jLabel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                    jLabel1.setIcon(thisGraph.getNode().get(i).getImageIcon().get(j));
                    jLabel1.setVisible(true);
                    jLabel1.setBounds((int)thisGraph.getNode().get(i).getX(),(int)thisGraph.getNode().get(i).getY(),195,163);           
                    jPanel1.add(jLabel1);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This method showPicture() is called in a buttonActionListener. 
And I also have another button which I want it to stop the image animations for all labels.

What I have tried: 
`Thread.sleep()` -> it freezes the button and it only shows the last image

I figured I had to use timer, but through all the topics I went they only used it on one label, not multiple labels.

**Edit**
->
i  read those examples given in the comments . and here is what i have resolved but it still is freezes the button and doesn't works :

```
int j = 0;
    public void showPicture(){
        //nodes : 
        for(int i=0;i<thisGraph.getNode().size();i++){
            if(thisGraph.getNode().get(i).getImageIcon()!=(null)){
              j=0;
                while( j<thisGraph.getNode().get(i).getImageIcon().size()){

                    if(j>0)
                        lables.get(lables.size()-1).setVisible(false);
                    JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();
                    lables.add(jLabel1);
                    jLabel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                    jLabel1.setIcon(thisGraph.getNode().get(i).getImageIcon().get(j));
                    jLabel1.setVisible(true);
                    jLabel1.setBounds((int)thisGraph.getNode().get(i).getX(),(int)thisGraph.getNode().get(i).getY(),195,163);

                    jPanel1.add(jLabel1);

                    //

                    ActionListener act;
                    act = new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            jLabel1.setVisible(true);        
                            j++;
                        }
                    };
                    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, act );
                    timer.start();

                    timer.stop();
                    //

                }
            }
        }}
```

Comment: *"what i have tried : Thread.sleep() -> it freezes the button"*. As it has been discussed multiple times in the forum, `Thread.sleep()` freezes the app because it stops the EDT. You need to use a Swing Timer, [for example...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877789/animated-sprites-with-java-swing/41879444#41879444)

Comment: Why it shows the last picture only? Because `showPicture()` method will run all the `for` loops and just show the last one. To correct this, again a `Swing Timer` would help, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46792479/2180785) is another example with a similar problem to the one you have

Comment: If after reading both examples and investigating you still cannot solve your problem, post a proper [mcve] with the improvements done after reading the above examples

Comment: i read those examples and i edited my text . please see it again @Frakcool

Comment: Did you read about the [mcve]? What part didn't you understand? Your example is far from being **complete**. *"but it still is freezes the button and doesn't works"* You're still using a `for` loop and a `while` loop inside it. You start the timer but stop it right after it starts..

Comment: Create ONE Swing `Timer`.  This will act as the "main-loop".  Each time the `Timer` ticks, you will loop through the `List` of labels and perform what ever task you need.  When you want to stop the animation, you call `stop` on the ONE `Timer`, when you want to start the animation, you call `start` on the ONE `Timer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing is single threaded and not thread safe.  This means that you shouldn't block the Event Dispatching Thread with long running or blocking operations, like `Thread.sleep`.  You should also, only ever update the UI (or anything it relies on) from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Probably the simplest solution to your problem is to use a Swing `Timer`.

The idea is a you use a single `Timer` to act as the "main animation loop", changing the properties of ALL the objects you need updated within it.

The following is pretty basic example, it animates 100 `JLabel`s, simply changing their background color with a randomly picked color

[image: Sparkle]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private List<JLabel> nodes = new ArrayList<>(100);

        private Random random = new Random();
        private Color[] colors = new Color[] { Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.BLACK, Color.MAGENTA};

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 10));
            for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel();
                label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
                label.setOpaque(true);
                label.setBackground(pickColor());
                nodes.add(label);
                add(label);
            }
            Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    for (JLabel label : nodes) {
                        label.setBackground(pickColor());
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        protected Color pickColor() {
            return colors[random.nextInt(colors.length)];
        }

    }

}
```

See [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details